# Error while installing npm install grunt-contrib-clean --dev-save

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Here is the `package.json` file

```
{
 "name": "gruntTutorial.js",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "^0.4.5"
  "grunt-contrib-clean":"^0.5.0"
   }
}
```

Having this `package.json` file, while installing npm `install grunt-contrib-clean --dev-save` I am getting below error.

```
C:\Users\prasad\Office\grunt>npm install grunt-contrib-clean --dev-save
C:\Users\prasad\Office\grunt
└── grunt-contrib-clean@0.7.0

npm WARN EJSONPARSE Failed to parse json
npm WARN EJSONPARSE Unexpected token 'g' at 13:6
npm WARN EJSONPARSE     "grunt-contrib-clean":"^0.5.0"
npm WARN EJSONPARSE      ^
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON grunt No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON grunt No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON grunt No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON grunt No license field.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `package.json` file doesn't parse because you're missing a comma at the end of

```
"grunt": "^0.4.5"
```

Also, the option is `--save-dev` not `--dev-save`.